# Can EKEvents be stored using another store(Other then EKEventStore)?

Tags: swift, macos, nscalendar, eventkit, corestore

I am using [Core Store](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore) in Swift for a MacOS project and I want to schedule Employees (modeled with `CoreStoreSchema`) into shifts (mathematically using [WCSP](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3477.pdf)). It's more complicated than that, but that is the basics.

I have here my Employee table, which I want to have multiple calendar events to represent when the employee is available. I also want to assign a int value with each event.

```swift
class Employee: CoreStoreObject {
        
        @Field.Stored("name")
        var name: String = ""
        
        
        // Here I want to store an array of Normal/Repeating Events
        @Field.Stored("timeFrames")
        var timeFrames: Array<EkEvent>
    }
```

For simplicity I only provided a single table with reduced data

---

What I need to model:

1. Normal and repeating events in same Array
2. the repeating attributes (If repeating)
3. Time start and end
4. Day

Reasons I don't want to use the `EKEventStore`:

1. It would decrease performance(Since it pulls from a different store) and complicate things with Core Store
2. I already have a store, and I don't want the events to be put on the user's calendar

Reasons I haven't modeled my own Calendar Events using Core Store:

1. I would just be rewriting the events from `EventKit`
2. EventKit has time zone features and other convent features that would be hard to replicate

If you want the full tables: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/YC4a6Lti) (just note it doesn't come with explanations)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood you correctly, I don't think you need EventKit. The two frameworks provided by Apple are for integration with their Calendar store (which then gets your event data into their first party Calendar.app).

The UI framework allows you to put Apple provided (and somewhat consistent Apple-styled UI) into your custom app. Most of these classes are built assuming you are using the underlying `Eventkit`.

But if you have your own events and your own UI, Apple provides the timezone, date, date formatting, and calendar-type support outside of EventKit.

Comment: FYI - `EKEventEditViewController` only works with EKEventStore. So this answer seems wrong for that reason.

Comment: What you are saying is true, but I think I'm giving the right answer for the question. I edited the answer, so it's more explicit for what you mentioned.